# sqlite database in android(fatal error)

Tags: android

i am begining in android.

i create sqlite database in android sdk 2.2, but generate a fatal error on belove code
help me..

first file

```
package com.and.database.demo;

import java.util.List;
import com.and.database.helper.MyHelperActivity;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MyDatabaseActivity extends Activity {

private TextView text_out;
private MyHelperActivity dh;
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);

    text_out = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.textout);
    this.dh = new MyHelperActivity(this);

    this.dh.deleteAll();

    this.dh.insert("durgesh");
    this.dh.insert("Mukesh");
    this.dh.insert("Sk");
    this.dh.insert("Givind");
    this.dh.insert("Parth");

    List<String> names = this.dh.SelectAll();
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    sb.append("Names in database:\n");

    for(String name : names)
    {
        sb.append(name + "\n");
    }

    Log.d("EXAMPLE", "names size - " + names.size());
    this.text_out.setText(sb.toString());
}
```

}

second file helper class.

```
package com.and.database.helper;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import android.content.Context;
import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement;
import android.util.Log;

public class MyHelperActivity {

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "mydata.db";
private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
private static final String TABLE_NAME = "mytable";

private Context context;
private SQLiteStatement insertstm;
private SQLiteDatabase db;

private static final String INSERT ="insert into " + TABLE_NAME + " (name) values(?)"; 

public MyHelperActivity(Context context) {
    this.context = context;
    OpenHelper openHelper = new OpenHelper(this.context);
    this.db = openHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    this.insertstm = this.db.compileStatement(INSERT);

}

public long insert (String name){
    this.insertstm.bindString(1, name);
    return this.insertstm.executeInsert();

}

public void  deleteAll() {
    this.db.delete(TABLE_NAME , null, null);
}

public List<String> SelectAll(){
    List<String>list = new ArrayList<String>();
    Cursor cursor = this.db.query(TABLE_NAME, new String[]{"name"}, null, null, null, null,"name desc");
      if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {

          do {
              list.add(cursor.getString(0));
          }while(cursor.moveToNext());
      }
      if (cursor != null && cursor.isClosed()) {
             cursor.close();
          }

    return list;

}

private static class OpenHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {


    public OpenHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

    }


    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

           db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)");

    }


    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

        Log.w("Example", "Upgrading database, this will drop tables and recreate.");
         db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_NAME);
         onCreate(db);
    }

}
```

}

following error generate belove

```
03-05 09:00:35.918: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(371): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
03-05 09:00:35.918: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(371): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.and.database.demo/com.and.database.demo.MyDatabaseActivity}: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: mytable: , while compiling: insert into mytable (name) values (?);
03-05 09:00:35.918: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(371):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2663)
03-05 09:00:35.918: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(371):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2679)
03-05 09:00:35.918: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(371):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$2300(ActivityThread.java:125)
03-05 09:00:35.918: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(371):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2033)
03-05 09:00:35.918: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(371):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
03-05 09:00:35.918: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(371):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
03-05 09:00:35.918: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(371):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4627)
03-05 09:00:35.918: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(371):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-05 09:00:35.918: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(371):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:521)
03-05 09:00:35.918: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(371):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:868)
03-05 09:00:35.918: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(371):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:626)
03-05 09:00:35.918: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(371):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-05 09:00:35.918: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(371): Caused by: android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such table: mytable: , while compiling: insert into mytable (name) values (?);
03-05 09:00:35.918: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(371):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)
03-05 09:00:35.918: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(371):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.compile(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:91)
03-05 09:00:35.918: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(371):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.<init>(SQLiteCompiledSql.java:64)
03-05 09:00:35.918: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(371):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteProgram.<init>(SQLiteProgram.java:80)
03-05 09:00:35.918: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(371):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteStatement.<init>(SQLiteStatement.java:36)
03-05 09:00:35.918: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(371):     at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.compileStatement(SQLiteDatabase.java:1145)
03-05 09:00:35.918: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(371):     at com.and.database.helper.MyHelperActivity.<init>(MyHelperActivity.java:29)
03-05 09:00:35.918: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(371):     at com.and.database.demo.MyDatabaseActivity.onCreate(MyDatabaseActivity.java:19)
03-05 09:00:35.918: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(371):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1047)
03-05 09:00:35.918: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(371):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2627)
03-05 09:00:35.918: ERROR/AndroidRuntime(371):     ... 11 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the code in `onCreate`() of OpenHelper is being executed, looks like you did not create the table.

Also, add @Override on top of the onCreate, onUpgrade

```
@Override 
public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {

       db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, name TEXT)");

}
```